# MySQL -- Select the minimum value of a column after selecting the minimum value of another column, and be in a specific range

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I got following table(tablea):

```
  x      y      z
--------------------
  3      0      2
  0      0      3
  0      3      2
  0      0      1
  0      0      4
```

i want to select all values in a specific row. The row has to fulfill specific requirements in that order (sorted by priority)

1. z has to be in a specific range (between 2 and 4)
2. x as low as possible
3. y as low as possible
4. z as low as possible

I got following code which fulfills requirement 1, 2 and 4:

```
Select x, MIN(z) AS z 
FROM tablea 
WHERE x = (SELECT MIN(x) FROM tablea where z between 2 AND 4)
and z between 2 AND 4;
```

I would also need requirement 3, what do i need to add in my code for that (or alternatively, completely different code)?

The result in my example should be x=0 y=0 z=3.

Edit: Second example

```
  x      y      z
--------------------
  3      0      2
  1      0      3
  0      3      2
  0      0      1
  0      2      4
```

Here x=0 y=2 z=4 should be selected.

Comment: How do you want to handle ties?  What about the case, say, you have one record with `x=0` `y=3` and `x=3` `y=0`?  How would you handle this?

Comment: x is a higher priority, so x=0 y=3 would be chosen

Comment: Would you able to live with taking the minimum of the sum of x and y?

Comment: No, the priorities have to be fulfilled in that fixed order (1, 2, 3 , 4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select t.*
from t
where z between 2 and 4
order by x, y, z
limit 1;
```

This chooses the lowest value of `x`, `y`, `z` in order (lowest x, then lowest y if there are ties, then lowest z if there are ties).  If you have some other definition, you can include that.  For instance, for the lowest sum:

```
select t.*
from t
where z between 2 and 4
order by x + y + z
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use derived tables to get the min values of x and y. Then `join` the results to the original table and select the min value of z.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b2011/3)

```
select t.x, t.y, min(t.z) as z
from tablename t 
join (select min(x) as minx from tablename where z between 2 and 4) mx
on t.x = mx.minx
join (select min(y) as miny from tablename where z between 2 and 4) my
on t.y = my.miny
where t.z between 2 and 4
group by t.x,t.y
```

Comment: Thanks! That works (at least in my example, i would have to test it in my real world table), any specific reason you added "group by" though, wouldn't it work without too?

Comment: `group by` is because you should `select` the min value of z too in the given range.

Comment: hmmm not sure if i understand. If i remove group by, x=0 y=0 z=3 also gets selected (and not x=0 y=0 z=4).

Comment: I made a second example (see edit), if i use your code on that, nothing gets selected.